# Github workflow-loop

Tags: github-actions

How to stop an infinite loop in a GitHub Actions workflow

This is my yml file

```
name: Safari Extension CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    tags:
      - '*'
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main   
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      stop:
        description: 'Stop the loop'    

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    if: github.actor != 'my_bot_account'
    steps:
      - name: Stop Loop
        if: github.event.inputs.stop == 'true'
        run: exit 0  # Terminate the workflow if 'stop' input is provided
        
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install Ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: '2.7'

      - name: Install Bundler
        run: gem install bundler
        working-directory: ./SafariExtApp
     
      - name: Install Node.js and NPM
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '14.x'

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
        working-directory: ./SafariExtApp

      - name: Run tests
        run: npm test
        working-directory: ./SafariExtApp


  build-and-release:
    needs: test
    if: github.event_name == 'release' || github.event_name == 'push'
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install Ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: '2.7'

      - name: Install Bundler
        run: gem install bundler
        working-directory: ./SafariExtApp
        
      - name: Install Node.js and NPM
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '14.x'

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
        working-directory: ./SafariExtApp   

      - name: Upload artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: artifacts
          path: ./SafariExtApp/dist/*.zip

      - name: Release extension
        uses: marvinpinto/action-automatic-releases@latest
        with:
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.xyz }}
          files: ./SafariExtApp/dist/*.zip
          title: safariext${{ github.event.release.tag_name }}-$(date +%s)
          prerelease: false
          draft: false
          automatic_release_tag: "Safari-New-Release"
```

Comment: What infinite loop? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Can you better explain what you want, where you expect an infinite loop and why you've done what you've done so far?  cause your workflow doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: I'm not sure you know, but when a GitHub Actions workflow does anything with GitHub using the `${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}`, no further workflows will trigger, so no loop can trigger.

Comment: If I had to guess your Release Extension task that creates a release will push a tag and that tag push triggers the repo again. Try replacing `${{ secrets.xyz }}` with `${{secrets.github_token}}` and make sure to add a `permission: contents: write` to the workflow to grant the workflow the correct permissions.

Comment: A manually triggered workflow run will just be *another* workflow run, it doesn't automatically replace an already scheduled run.